# I have a search and checkbox filter that should be filtering together, but my checkbox filter code isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, my checkbox filter isn't working but my search filter is. What's wrong with it? Here is my search + checkbox filter below:

```
// search filter (working)

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").keyup(function() {

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;

    // Loop through the comment list
    $("tr").each(function() {

      // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
      if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hidden');

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
      } else {
        $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
        count++;
      }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text("Number of Rows = " + count);
  });
});


// checkbox filter (not working)

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable tr' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

  $('div.modal-body').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function() {

    if ($('div.modal-body').find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
      $('#myTable tr').hide();
      $('div.modal-body').find('input:checked').each(function() {
        $('#myTable tr' + $(this).attr('rel')).not('.hidden').show();
      });
    } else {
      $('#myTable tr').not('.hidden').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried with `on` instead of `live` like `$('div.modal-body').find('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {`?

Comment: it worked!! Thank you! I just looked it up, that the live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Thanks!

Comment: Great. added this as answer so that it helps other users facing same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live` is depreciated in latest versions of jquery, use `on` instead for your event.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable tr' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

        $('div.modal-body').find('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {

            if($('div.modal-body').find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
            $('#myTable tr').hide();
            $('div.modal-body').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('#myTable tr' + $(this).attr('rel')).not('.hidden').show();
            });
            } else {
                $('#myTable tr').not('.hidden').show();
            }
        });
    });
```